# MYSQL combining two tables with self created columns

Tags: mysql

Hi I have two different queries for these two tables which are as followed:

Table 1 :

[image]

Table 2 :

[image]

```
[1] select exerciseId, sum(frustrated = 'Y') as Frustrated,
sum(frustrated = 'N') as NotFrustrated
from selfreportfrustration
group by exerciseId;
```

and

```
[2] SELECT exercisesId, count(*) as total FROM exerciseprogress GROUP BY 
exercisesId;
```

How do I combine these two queries into a single query so that I can have a single view with 4 columns instead? If I'm not wrong both exerciseId and exercisesId are the same so they can be joined. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use left join

```
select a.*, b.total 
from

(select exerciseId, sum(frustrated = 'Y') as Frustrated,
sum(frustrated = 'N') as NotFrustrated
from selfreportfrustration
group by exerciseId) a 

left join 
(SELECT exercisesId, count(*) as total FROM exerciseprogress GROUP BY 
exercisesId) b 
on a.exerciseId=b.exercisesId
```

Comment: The first solution gave me this error: "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'exercisesId' in 'group statement'." 

The second solution gave me this error: "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'total' in 'field list'."


It's a little confusing as both exerciseId and exercisesId refer to the same thing, but the database I got was like this.

Comment: modified the answer, it was a typo you can check now @JohnNo

Comment: Now the error I get is: "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'exerciseId' in 'field list'." instead.

Comment: which case you are executing - first one or second one?

Comment: The first one. Second one gives the same error as stated in the first comment

Comment: I've modifed the answer but if your column name are ok then it will give you result for sure @JohnNo

Answer (score 0):

Here is one query :

```html
select main.exerciseId, sum(main.frustrated = 'Y') as Frustrated,sum(main.frustrated = 'N') as NotFrustrated,
(SELECT count(*) FROM exerciseprogress WHERE exercisesId = main.exerciseId) as total
from selfreportfrustration AS main
group by exerciseId;
```